# TYPO3, Plesk and permissions

Tags: permissions, typo3, plesk, parallels

I have a permission problem on an old TYPO3 v. 4.2.9. Additionally, I have Plesk Control Panel 8.6. The user is the ftp user and group is `psacln`. CGI PHP is used (`php_sapi_name();`). PHP support (with safe mode), CGI support and Perl support is activated (shown under webhosting setup).

I don't know if it is correct, but currently seems to work:

757 on the following folders:

- fileadmin
- fileadmin/_temp_
- fileadmin/templates (and all subfolders -files)
- fileadmin/customfolder
- typo3 (and all subfolders -files)
- typo3conf
- typo3conf/ext (and all subfolders -files)
- typo3conf/l10n (and all subfolders -files)
- typo3temp
- uploads
- uploads/media
- uploads/pics
- uploads/tf

All other folders have 750 and all other files 644.

If I don't use these permissions I get `access denied` and `Cannot find tslib/. Please set path by defining $configured_tslib_path in index.php.`.

[Here](http://www.tanmar.info/content/view/33/62/) it is written that you should use the user `wwwrun` instead of the ftp user and switch to 646 if you need to change some files with your ftp user. But I think there is no such user wwwrun.

I uploaded a file and it has the ftpuser as owner and 644 as permission.

**Questions:**

- Why do I have to set such high permissions? Is the problem that I need to have such high permissions that the apache user is another than the ftp user and otherwise it doesn't work? Isn't there a way to have the same user for ftp and for apache?
- Is only the old TYPO3 v. 4.2 needing such high permissions? Are there other ways to change to a lower permission?
- I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why do I have to set such high permissions?**

With good configuration you don't. `typo3` and `t3lib` need to be readonly. `fileadmin`, `typo3conf`, `typo3temp`, `uploads` need to be writeable but **only** to the user under which PHP runs.

**Is the problem that I need to have such high permissions that the apache user is another than the ftp user and otherwise it doesn't work?**

IMHO, as the PHP is run as CGI, it actually runs under different user than Apache. As files are generated by PHP and have its permissions, they might not be readable by Apache. Therefore you should have Apache and PHP in the same group and have files and permissions set on the per group basis.

**Isn't there a way to have the same user for ftp and for apache?**

That's a question for your host. Same group should do the job though.

**Is only the old TYPO3 v. 4.2 needing such high permissions?**

I think there's not any difference between v4.2 and new versions in this.

**Are there other ways to change to a lower permission?**

Yes, check who is who. You possibly have up to 3 users involved: Apache, PHP, FTP user. To access the files created by each other, they need to be in the same group and the files need to have permissions set for this group. Then check the TYPO3 settings for creation of new folders and files:

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['createGroup'] = 'group_of_your_users';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['fileCreateMask'] = '0770';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['folderCreateMask'] = '0770';
```

Comment: Now I tried to set 0755 on folders and 0644 on files and it works. `createGroup` is empty, `fileCreateMask` is 0644, `folderCreateMask` is 0755. Before I tried to have 0750 on folders and 0640 on files, but that didn't worked. Seems that Apache/PHP is not in the same group on this host (because others needs read rights). With 0755 only the owner has write rights, so it seems that the PHP user is the owner (and the same user as the FTP user?). Thanks for your answer! It made things much more clearer.

Comment: Check newly created files in the `typo3temp` folder to see what ownership they have. Compare it with files created by the FTP user and user/group under which Apache runs. This should give you a clear picture of who is who and who can access what. Then you can try altering those three TYPO3 configuration options to tune permissions and ownership of files created by TYPO3.

Comment: Also, you should be aiming for permissions which don't allow the files to be read by "others". Only the owner and group members should be allowed to access files.

Comment: Thanks again for your suggestions. Files created in `typo3temp` have the ftp user as owner. If I upload a file with FTP in this folder its again the ftp user. But I don't know how to find out under which user/group Apache runs. Do I have to change these three TYPO3 configurations? I tried to set files to 0640 but than nothing worked anymore because of access denied. So I think I can't disallow reading by "others".

Comment: The user Apache runs as probably won't be mentioned in the `phpinfo()` as the PHP runs as CGI so ask the webhoster/admin to find out. Apache most probably needs to read the files only so if you set `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['createGroup']` to the one Apache is a member of, everything should work. The only problem you will then face though is files uploaded by the FTP user as IMHO you won't be able to set correct group through FTP. You will either have to use some other tool or set less strict permissions for files uploaded via FTP.

Comment: Some more questions: I tried to set `typo3` and `t3lib` folder (including all subfolders and files) to `0440` but that don't worked (Cannot find tslib). I thought that I would only need read permissions? Can there be a difference between ssh and ftp user?

Comment: Follow-Up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300160/what-are-the-lowest-possible-permissions-for-typo3 The last questions concerns TYPO3 in general because of other project.

Comment: What about 0750? Does it work? **If yes**, you don't have to make it tighter. **If no**, does turning off *safe mode* help with these permissions? In theory there can be difference between the SSH and FTP user but I think that's never the case with most of the webhosters. Just compare the ownership of files created by the SSH and FTP user.